# PostgreSQL error: Could not rename temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp"

Tags: postgresql, logging

In my log file (\data\pg_log), PostgreSQL 9.3.2 for Windows (x86-32), I constantly get the following error:

```
EST LOG:  could not rename temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp" to "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
```

I thought about the folder permissions, and allowed read/write to all users on \data\pg_stat_tmp, but it persists.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Check your antivirus and make sure it excludes your data directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL statistics issue - could not rename temporary statistics file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846804/postgresql-statistics-issue-could-not-rename-temporary-statistics-file)